# Issue with Communication Between Services Using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am facing a communication issue between two services within the same Docker container using Docker Compose. My docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  web_frontend:
    container_name: web_frontend
    hostname: web_frontend
    build:
      context: ./vero_webapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_nextjs
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - web_backend

  web_backend:
    container_name: web_backend
    hostname: web_backend
    build:
      context: ./apiveroprodutos
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

The issue arises when I attempt to access the URL http://web_backend:8000; I receive an ENOTFOUND error (getaddrinfo). This call occurs during the docker compose up right after the backend container is started, and the front-end one is finishing. It attempts to make the call and breaks with the error I pointed out, without even completing the build. From my understanding, Docker Compose should establish a link between the services based on the hostname, allowing seamless communication. Issue sample:

```
1.071    Creating an optimized production build ...
39.62  ✓ Compiled successfully
39.62    Linting and checking validity of types ...
39.75    Collecting page data ...
41.02 http://web_backend:8000/bling/api/product/searchAndPagination?
41.06 Products Api Error: TypeError: fetch failed
41.06     at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
41.06     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
41.06   cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND web_backend
41.06       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
41.06       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
41.06     errno: -3008,
41.06     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
41.06     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
41.06     hostname: 'web_backend'
41.06   }
41.06 }
```

I've checked the configuration, and it seems correct. However, I'm still encountering the communication problem. Can someone please help me identify what might be causing this issue or suggest a solution? Am I missing any configurations or steps to enable proper communication between the services?

Comment: The configuration looks correct. Is the `web_backend` running? Do you have a reproducer, e.g. a git repository? --- "*I am facing a communication issue between two services within the same Docker container*" - The services are running in distinct containers.

Comment: "*... without even completing the build.*" - Just to be sure: this happens during the image build process?

Comment: The code is private :-( Do you think it could be related to the specific Dockerfile of the Django API or the NextJS App?

Comment: Yes! I'm running a 'docker compose up --build --force-recreate.

Comment: Please post the full log of `docker compose up ...`. If it really fails during the image build phase, it is no wonder the call fails (first the images are built, then the containers are started. Thus, the `web_backend` container will not be available when the images are built).

Comment: Indeed! There was a call made for optimization that was causing a break. I removed it and managed to finish creating the image. The error has now changed to: 'Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'web_backend:8000'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) - I would recommend a separate post for the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, thanks to all the friends who were here to help! The issue was in the most ridiculous thing of all – the use of an underscore in the name. Apologies for the naivety.

Answer (score -1):

In order for your services to communicate together, they should be in the same network. Create a network and add both your services to this network and it should work

Code :

```yaml
services:
  web_frontend:
    container_name: web_frontend
    hostname: web_frontend
    build:
      context: ./vero_webapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_nextjs
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - web_backend
    networks:
      - my_network

  web_backend:
    container_name: web_backend
    hostname: web_backend
    build:
      context: ./apiveroprodutos
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
    my_network:
```

Comment: The error remains the same when I try to build with docker compose up

Comment: If no network is specified, they are by default on the same network.